# webhosting php script

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registration

I have purchased a cPanel/WHM web hosting reseller account and I want to set up a site for people to set up a hosting accounts. I also would like to have a domain name registration system on the site, so people can register the domain name they would like to host with me. How can I do this? Are there any ready-made scripts available or should I create my own script using the WHM API?

Comment: I'd like to run my own car manufacturing empire, but first does anyone know what these round things with rubber on their edges are called???

Comment: sorry I didnt get you

Comment: I assume you intend to run this service as a business? if so perhaps you should have figured out these answers before starting? It's also a remarkably open/unspecific "question" too - very hard to answer without either spending a lot of time discussing the setup with you or alternatively not bothering because you've invested about 2 minutes writing a detail-less question requiring very significantly more investment in answering.

Comment: Well said @Chopper3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really have two questions here. The first is how to set up a site where people can purchase hosting and have the site automatically set up the hosting accounts in WebHost Manager. The second is how to create an online domain name registration system. I think these are both on topic here at ServerFault, but only barely... they both have to do with programming and might be more at home on StackOverflow.

In answer to your first question, you might want to look at software like [phpHostBot](http://www.idevspot.com/PhpHostBot.php) which is an online signup solution for cPanel. There's a number of other scripts and resources out there, that was the first one I could find which looked like it might meet your needs. Read through the [cPanel forums for more suggestions](http://forums.cpanel.net/cpanel-whm-discussions.html)

As for domain name registrations, you'll need to start by choosing a registrar with a reseller program. I know they're somewhat unpopular but [GoDaddy has cheap rates and a reseller plan](http://www.godaddy.com/reseller/domain-reseller.aspx) however there are a lot of other domain name registrars out there. Many of them will also provide you with iFrameble interfaces or other helpful scripts.

Good luck!